# Mail plugin in Grails

Tags: grails, gradle, dependency-injection

I am trying to send mail through my grails app. I am using [this](http://grails.org/plugin/mail) plugin. I have put it in `build.gradle` like so:

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:mail:1.0.7"
```

and have refreshed the project. After that, I started Grails (v3) and did `run-app`. When I try to run `sendMail`, I get this exception:

[image]

Here is my call, `email` and `message` are variables of type `String`:

```
sendMail {
    to email
    subject "Contact"
    body message
}
```

On the plugin documentation, it says:

> The mail plug-in provides a MailService that can be used anywhere in your Grails application. The MailService provides a single method called sendMail that takes a closure. In addition the sendMail method is injected into all controllers to simplify access.

I have never done dependicy injection (which isn't needed), but I tried declaring a `def mailService` and then calling `mailService.sendMail`, but got a `NullPointerException` on `mailService`.

I don't think it matters, but I do not have a mail server installed/running, but I would doubt that this would cause method not found errors.

I can confirm that the correct dependency is showing up in the Gradle view of IntelliJ IDEA so it's installing the thing correctly.

Comment: If you do Grails, you do dependency injection.

Comment: What happens if you run: grails install-plugin mail

Comment: @pczeus "$ grails install-plugin mail
| Error Command not found install-plugin
Did you mean: install or list-plugins or plugin-info?"

Comment: That doesn't look like the proper version of the Mail plugin for Grails 3. It should be version 2.0.0.RC4, see here: https://bintray.com/grails/plugins/mail/view

Comment: I took it directly from the mail plugin site: https://grails.org/plugin/mail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of Mail plugin you are using is not compatible with Grails 3. If you want to use that plugin go to this url:

https://bintray.com/grails/plugins/mail/view

An select the version you want. All compatible plugins with Grails 3 are in https://bintray.com/grails/plugins, not in the oldest url from grails.org

An example of usage:

```
import grails.plugins.mail.MailService

@Transactional
class SendMailService {

    MailService mailService

    def sendMail(email, subjectMail, bodyMail) {
        mailService.sendMail {
             to email
             subject subjectMail
             html bodyMail
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I know this should work, I'm going to assume that when you said you "tried using `def mailService`" that you did so in the wrong place.

Your controller should work if you do something like:

```
class ContactController {
    def mailService   // note it must be outside of any methods/closure

    def someAction() {
        String email = "bob@gmail.com"
        String message = "This is the email text"
        // some code here is fine
        mailService.sendMail {
            to email
            subject "Contact"
            body message
        }
       // more code here is fine
   }
}
```

See how the injected service must be named "mailService", and must exist outside of any closures or actions.   Grails will look for any class named MailService, instantiate it, and inject it, automatically setting the variable mailService equal to a reference to the service.

This all presumes you have the right service for whatever version of Grails you're using